# Hardcoding a python datetime

Tags: python

I have a datetime where the input is hardcoded as `datetime.datetime(2008,5,5,16,20)`

In the same format how to get the current datetime?  I am using python 2.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 18, 10, 59, 42, 518352)
```

For more info, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).